# AST selector for `interface`, `type`, `const`, `var`, `let` from the global scope only

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint, eslint-plugin-jsdoc

I am writing a TypeScript project, which is meant to be run on Node (after transpilation). I have ESLint with plugins: `@typescript-eslint` and `eslint-plugin-jsdoc`.

I am trying to configure `eslint-plugin-jsdoc` plugin through `settings.jsdoc.contexts` setting to require JSDoc comments on global `interface`s, `type`s, `const`s, `var`s, `let`s, + the default contexts (`function`s, `class`es, etc).

What are the AST selectors for `interface`s, `type`s, `const`s, `var`s, `let` in the global scopes?

I tried to find a TypeScript-specific list of AST nodes, but even if I were able to, I wouldn't know how to specify `interface`s, `type`s, `const`s, `var`s, `let` from global scope only.

Comment: Are you saying they aren't specified in the documentation? If that's the case, sadly your best bet probably is just experimenting and debugging on your own code directly.

Comment: @JoannaFalkowska Nope, there are none i could find. the only docs on AST selectors / nodes i could find was by eslint itself: [`esint/eslint-visitor-keys`](https://github.com/eslint/eslint-visitor-keys/blob/main/lib/visitor-keys.js), but I was able to solve this problem on my own with [`typescript-eslint's playgrond`](https://typescript-eslint.io/play/)` it shows `AST nodes` of the pasted code via `ESTree` tab.

Answer (score 0):

So I was unable to find any documentation, but I was able to find a tool; [`typescript-eslint`'s playground](https://typescript-eslint.io/play/) which has an option (`ESTree` tab) to convert pasted code into `AST`.

Which means i can paste code like:

```
interface IFoo {
    foo: "__foo__";
}

type TFoo = {
    foo: "__foo__";
}

// ...
```

and discover;

- `interface`'s AST selector is `"TSInterfaceDeclaration"`,
- `type`'s AST selector is `"TSTypeAliasDeclaration "`

on top of that, I discovered that a file's (?) root element is `"Program"` so; `VariableDeclaration[parent.type="Program"]` IMHO should select `"VariableDeclaration"` nodes whose `parent` is of type `"Program"`, aka the global scope.

**IDK if the same is true for multi-file environments.**

my `settings.jsdoc.contexts`:

```
const eslintConfig = {
    settings: {
        jsdoc: {
            contexts: [
                "VariableDeclaration[parent.type=\"Program\"]",    // global variables
                "TSInterfaceDeclaration[parent.type=\"Program\"]", // global interfaces
                "TSTypeAliasDeclaration[parent.type=\"Program\"]", // global types  
                "ClassDeclaration",
                "ClassExpression",                               // idk what's the diff between "ClassExplression" and "ClassDeclaration" so i added it just in case.
                "FunctionDeclaration",
                "FunctionExpression"                             // same.
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**This is only a 1st draft, I am still testing it, so am not 100% sure if it works as I want it to work**

---

**resources:**
(just in case)

- https://eslint.org/docs/latest/extend/selectors#what-syntax-can-selectors-have
- https://github.com/eslint/eslint-visitor-keys/blob/main/lib/visitor-keys.js
- https://dev.to/mlennox/ast-selectors-rule-286i